# Transferir e somar valores de uma coluna SQL

Tags: php, sql

Tenho duas colunas em uma tabela, preciso que os valores da coluna 1 sejam transferidos e somados aos valores da coluna 2.

Isso pode ser feito com um PHP ou existe alguma maneira mais fácil de ser feito?

```
Original:
ID /  1  /  2  /
1    150   100
2    200   50
3    75    175

Como deve ficar:
ID /  1  /  2  /
1     0    250
2     0    250
3     0    250
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo para fazer isto em SQL. Você não deu muitos detalhes sobre a tabela mas basicamente é isto para fazer em todos as linhas:

```
UPDATE tabela SET col2 = col1 + col2, col1 = 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/SumColumn.sql).

Isto está somando as duas colunas e jogando o resultado na segunda, como você diz querer.